# Non-zero exit code (101) (PyCharm)

Tags: python, pycharm

*Недавно скачал PyCharm и создал свой проект ,но появилась вот такая ошибка*

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Уже много ,где смотрел ,но так и не смог решить свою проблему.
Вопрос: Стоит ли волноваться из-за неё?
   // + возможно вы знаете как это решить

Comment: 1) не стоит запускать с привилегиями администратора 2) не стоит ставить программы в APPDATA (а у продуктов jetbrains дурная привычка пихать туда все по-умолчанию 3) не стоит использовать пути, в которых есть пробелы

Comment: @user7860670 PyCharm не имеет отношения к установке Python в AppData, это дефолтный путь установщика с python.org на Windows для текущего пользователя.